# $L^p$ measurable functions equality

Tags: measure-theory

Suppose $1<p<\infty$ and $f,g \in L^p (X,M,\mu)$. Where $||f||_P$ and $||g||_p$ are non zero, and
$||f+g||_p = ||f||_p +||g||_p$ .

Proving that equality:
$${f \over ||f||_p} = {g \over ||g||_p} \text{ }\mu -a.e.$$

What theorem is available for that prove? I can't find start point.

Comment: See [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/87636/8271)

Comment: @leo: while t.b.'s answer there can be moved this way to get an answer, I don't think they are exactly dupes.

Comment: @WillieWong I just realized that this is about Minkowski's inequality. I have read the question too fast. Sorry about that. You are right this a good question in his own right. However, the conditions to equality in Minkowski's inequality are the same of Hölder's inequality.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The triangle inequality (Minkowski) is proven using Hölder. To show what you want, you can repeat that argument:

(note that $q(p-1)=p$)

$$
\|f\|_p+\|g\|_p=\|f+g\|_p=\left(\int|f+g|^p\right)^{1/p}=\left(\int|f+g|\,|f+g|^{p-1}\right)^{1/p}\leq\left(\int|f|\,|f+g|^{p-1}+\int|g|\,|f+g|^{p-1}\right)^{1/p}
\leq\left(\|f\|_p \left(\int|f+g|^p\right)^{1/q}+\|g\|_p \left(\int|f+g|^p\right)^{1/q}\right)^{1/p}
=\left((\|f\|_p+\|g\|_p)\left(\int|f+g|^p\right)^{1/q} \right)^{1/p}
=\left(\|f+g\|_p \|f+g\|_p^{p/q} \right)^{1/p}
=\left(\|f+g\|_p \|f+g\|_p^{p-1} \right)^{1/p}
=\left( \|f+g\|_p^{p} \right)^{1/p}
=\|f+g\|_p=\|f\|_p+\|g\|_p
$$

In particular we have equality in the two Hölder inequalities we used in the middle (the second "$\leq$"). Equality in Hölder occurs only when  the $p$ and $q$ powers of the two factors are linearly dependent. This means that there exist constants $\alpha,\beta$ such that 
$$
|f|^p=\alpha|f+g|^{q(p-1)},\ \ |g|^p=\beta|f+g|^{q(p-1)}
$$
almost everywhere.

So $|g|^p=\gamma|f|^p$ a.e. for some constant $\gamma$, and then $|g|=\delta|f|$ a.e. for yet another constant. Then 
$$
\frac{|f|}{\|f\|_p}=\frac{|g|}{\|g\|_p}\ \ \ \text{a.e.}
$$

Comment: Perfect answer. Thanks @MartinArgerami