# is there a sufficient and necessary condition for which the equality in Minkowski inequality holds when $p= \infty$?

Tags: real-analysis, inequality

is there a sufficient and necessary condition for Minkowski inequality when $p= \infty$?

i.e. When does the equality $\|f\|_\infty+ \|g\|_\infty =\|f+g\|_\infty  $ hold?

The norm here is the essential supremum

Comment: If $\|f\|_{\infty}$ the essential supremum of $|f|$ or just $\sup|f|$ ?

Comment: Oh, I am sorry, it's essential supremum

Answer (score 5):

This [has been asked before](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/246068/147263), with no answer given. I'll argue that there is no answer that is not tautological: there are so many pairs $(f,g)$ for which the equality holds, that the property $\|f+g\|_\infty=\|f\|_\infty+\|g\|_\infty$ is the simplest description of all such pairs.

For simplicity, scale the functions so that $\|f\|_\infty=1=\|g\|_\infty$. Introduce the vector-valued function $H(x)=(f(x),g(x))$ and let $R$ denote its [essential range](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Essential_range): the smallest closed subset of $\mathbb R^2$ such that the set $\{x:H(x)\notin R\}$ has measure zero. So, $R$ is a compact subset of $[-1,1]^2$.

The equality $\|f+g\|_\infty$  holds if and only if $R\cap \{(1,1),(-1,-1)\}$ is nonempty. Indeed, the function $(x,y)\mapsto |x+y|$ attains its extreme values on $R$, so in order for its supremum to be $2$, the set $R$ has to contain a point where the value $2$ is attained.

How to describe the compact subsets of $[-1,1]^2$ that contain either $(1,1)$ or $(-1,-1)$? Well, they are what they are.