# Show that $\|F\|=\|f\|_q$.

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

> Let $L^q$ be the space of $L^q$-integrable functions on the complete measure space $(X,B,\mu)$. Let $f$ be a given function in $L^q$. Define $F$ on $L^p$ by $F(g)=\int fg\,d\mu$. Show that $\|F\|=\|f\|_q$.

$$|F(g)|=\left|\int fgd\mu\right|\le\int |fg|d\mu\le\|f\|_q\|g\|_p$$ by Holder's inequality. So we have $\|F\|\le\|f\|_q$. But how do you show that $\|F\|\ge\|f\|_q$?

Comment: Can you show the equality actually holds for some $f$?

Comment: Maybe you should think about the [Equality case in Hölder's and Minkowski's inequality](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/87636/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is called duality principle for L^P spaces.If you have royden's real analysis you may look at the solution or look at this place lemma 4.2 http://press.princeton.edu/chapters/s9627.pdf
the main idea is to construct a proper g of norm 1