# Hölder's inequality, equality condition

Tags: real-analysis, lp-spaces

It is known that equality in Holder's inequality (i.e $|\int_Efg|=||f||_p||g||_q$)  holds iff $\|g\|_q^q|f|^p=\|f\|_p^p|g|^q$ a.e.  However recently I read somewhere that an additional constraint must me met, that of $\operatorname{sgn}(f)=\operatorname{sgn}(g)$ a.e.  Can anyone help me understand why this additional constraint is needed?

Comment: Can't remember when equality holds in Holder except when $p=2=q$, which one can scratch out on a napkin at gunpoint if necessary. There the equality holds iff there is a scalar $a$ such that $f=ag$ a.e.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Normally, Hölder's inequality is written as
$$\int_E|fg|\le \|f\|_p\|g\|_q \tag{1}$$
that is, with absolute value inside the integral. For this version, you don't need the additional constraint on absolute value in the equality case (analyzed in 
[On the equality case of the Hölder and Minkowski inequalites](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/87636/)).

The inequality for $\left| \int_Efg\right|$ is obtained by combining $(1)$ with the integral triangle inequality 
$$\left| \int_Efg\right|\le \int_E |fg|\tag{2}$$
Equality holds in (2) if and only if $fg$ is either nonnegative a.e. or nonpositive a.e. Indeed, the proof of (2) involves observing that
$$ \int_E (|fg|-fg) \ge 0$$ and 
$$ \int_E (|fg|+fg) \ge 0$$ and the equality cases here are clear.