# The equality case of Hölder's inequality at the endpoint $p=1$, $q=\infty$

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-integral, lp-spaces

This is a follow-up question on [On the equality case of the Hölder and Minkowski inequalites](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/87636/).

What is the conditions for $$\int \vert fg\vert =\Vert f \Vert_p\Vert g \Vert_q$$ when  $p=1, q= \infty$?

It's seems like that the same proof won't work, as $q = \infty $.

Comment: A sufficient condition is when $g$ is s constant (and $f$ is arbitrary).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $\displaystyle \int|fg|=\|f\|_1\,\|g\|_\infty$, this can be written as
$$
\int|fg|=\int|f|\,\|g\|_\infty. 
$$
Rewrite as
$$
\int |f|\,(\|g\|_\infty-|g|)=0.
$$
So a necessary and sufficient condition for the equality is that $|g|=\|g\|_\infty$ a.e. whenever $f\ne0$.