# A dual norm optimization problem

Tags: optimization, duality-theorems, dual-spaces, matrix-norms

I'm reading this machine learning optimization paper https://arxiv.org/pdf/2010.01412.pdf. At the last formula of page 3, they derived an optimization problem like this:

${\bf{\epsilon^*(w)}} = \underset{||\bf{\epsilon}||_p \leq\rho}{\operatorname{argmax}}
\bf{\epsilon^{T}\nabla_{w}L_s(w)}$ (1)

They said this is a classical dual norm problem and the solution is:

$\bf{\hat\epsilon(w) = \rho sign(\nabla_{w}L_s(w))}|\nabla_{w}L_s(w)|^{q-1}/(||\nabla_{w}L_s(w)||_q^q)^{\frac{1}{p}}$ (2)

with $\frac{1}{p}+\frac{1}{q} = 1$ and $|.|^{q-1}$ denotes elementwise absolute value and power.

Can anyone please show me how to solve the optimization problem to arrive at the second formulas. I really appreciate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First off, to reduce unnecessary clutter, let
$$
x=\nabla\mathbf{_wL_s(w)}\ ,
$$
and
$$
\hat{\epsilon}=\hat{\epsilon}\mathbf{(w)} .
$$
Then equation $(2)$ becomes
$$
\hat{\epsilon}=\frac{\rho\,\mathbf{sign}(x)|x|^{q-1}}{\|x\|_q^\frac{q}{p}}\ .
$$
Immediately before their equation $(2)$, the authors of your cited paper note that "$\  |\cdot|^{q-1}\ $ denotes elementwise absolute value and power".  Although they don't say so explicitly, the same interpretation must be applied to the function $\ \mathbf{sign(\cdot)}\ $.  The equation can therefore be written as
$$
\hat{\epsilon}_i=\frac{\rho\,\mathbf{sign}(x_i)|x_i|^{q-1}}{\|x\|_q^\frac{q}{p}}\ .
$$
With $\ \hat{\epsilon}\ $ thus defined, a little algebraic manipulation, making liberal use of the identity $\ p+q=pq\ $, gives
$$
\|\hat{\epsilon}\|_p=\rho
$$
and
$$
\hat{\epsilon}^\mathbf{T}x=\rho\|x\|_q\ .
$$
But [Hölder's inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/H%C3%B6lder%27s_inequality) tells us that
$$
\epsilon^\mathbf{T}x\le\|\epsilon\|_p\|x\|_q\le \rho\|x\|_q
$$
if $\ \|\hat{\epsilon}\|_p\le\rho\ $.  Thus, on the closed ball $\ \big\{\,\epsilon\,\big|\,\|\epsilon\|_p\le\rho\big\}\ $, the linear function $\ \epsilon^\mathbf{T}x\ $ of $\ \epsilon\ $ is bounded above by $\ \rho\|x\|_q\ $, and achieves that bound for $\ \epsilon=\hat{\epsilon}\ $. It follows that
$$
\hat{\epsilon}=\arg\max_{\|\epsilon\|_p\le\rho}\epsilon^\mathbf{T}x\ .
$$

Comment: thank you! it's a great proof. It took me some writing to fully understand what you showed. I really appreciate it. I have to say the solution they wrote looks a bit daunting with the sign(x) but i guess it doesnt matter when multiplying epsilon_hat with x:)

Comment: Thank you, but there's not really much of anything original in the proof.  If you look up any proof that an $\ L_q\ $ space is the dual of an $L_p$ space,  it will follow much the same lines.

Comment: Since lonza only showed how to verify that it is a solution and not how to actually derive this solution, this can be done using the fact that we have equality in Hoelders Inequality iff $|\hat \epsilon|^p = |x|^q \frac{\|\hat \epsilon\|_{p}^p}{\|x\|_{q}^q}$. This can be transformed such that we get the absolute of the components of $\hat \epsilon$. The $sign(x)$ follows since said inequality only holds for the absolute of the scalar product. It ensures that the scalar product and the absolute of it are equal.

Comment: The fact that equality holds if said equality holds is nicely shown here https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/87636/on-the-equality-case-of-the-h%C3%B6lder-and-minkowski-inequalities .